# After server spawning a new thread respond to the client

Tags: java, multithreading, rest

I am developing a web application with multithreading. The concept is that the clients send requests to the server. The server creates a new thread to execute a procedure (delete a foder by Town name).
For the client request and the server response I am using RESTful web services.

Here is the code for the server:

```
    @GET
    @Path("/Data_Availability/{Town}

    public Response Data_availability( 
                @PathParam("Town") String Town) throws Exception{

        Delete_Dir Procedure = new Delete_Dir();
        Thread thread = new Thread(Procedure);
        thread.Start();

return Response.ok("Done").build();  // Normally here is the response. But since I create
                                     // a new thread this will be always "Done"
    }
```

And here the code for the procedure:

```
public class Delete_Dir implements Runnable{

    String Town;
    public void run() {

        try {
            execute();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Delete_Dir( String Town_ ){
        Town = Town_;
    }

    public void execute(){

        try{
            File file = new File("c://" + Town);
            FileUtils.deleteDirectory(file);

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I respond to the client through the class Delete_Dir ?? Since I create a new thread if I place the response where I placed it above it will be always "Done".

Comment: Why not wait for the execute method to finish? The server will thread on its own all the incoming requests, and you can respond with the actual result.

Comment: How can I check when the thread is finished ?? For example I tried the Thread.sleep(500); and then change a variable result = "done"; It worked but I don't want to use 500ms. I would be best if I new when the thread is finished. What is the command ?

Comment: Do not use a thread; just do a Procedure.execute() instead of using a Thread.

Comment: If I do that will not run as multithreading. The requests will be in the row for one thread only. I want to execute the requests concurently.

Comment: The application server itself is multithreaded, and the method Data_availability() *will* be called from multiple threads concurrently; if you have other requirements (f.e. if the deletion will take long enough to deplete the application server's thread pool, or if the application server has a had limit on the time spent in each thread) then it's a different matter.